A problem with `std::totally_ordered` and `std::basic_const_iterator` inside another iterator
The following code does not compile at all because of (probably) infinity recursion of concepts.
Actually I get a

C:/Program Files/mingw64/include/c++/13.2.0/concepts:318:11: error:
satisfaction of atomic constraint 'requires(const typename
std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t, const typename
std::remove_reference<_Arg>::type& __u) {{__t < __u} -> decltype(auto)
[requires std::__detail::__boolean_testable<, >];{__t >
__u} -> decltype(auto) [requires std::__detail::__boolean_testable<, >];{__t <= __u} ->
decltype(auto) [requires
std::__detail::__boolean_testable<, >];{__t >= __u} ->
decltype(auto) [requires
std::__detail::__boolean_testable<, >];{__u < __t} ->
decltype(auto) [requires
std::__detail::__boolean_testable<, >];{__u > __t} ->
decltype(auto) [requires
std::__detail::__boolean_testable<, >];{__u <= __t} ->
decltype(auto) [requires
std::__detail::__boolean_testable<, >];{__u >= __t} ->
decltype(auto) [requires
std::__detail::__boolean_testable<, >];} [with _Tp =
permutated_iterator<std::basic_const_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned char*, std::span<const unsigned char, 2> > >,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::span<int, 2> > >; _Up = permutated_iterator<std::basic_const_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned char*, std::span<const unsigned char, 2> > >,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::span<int, 2> > >]' depends on itself

I really don't understand why.
#include <span>
#include <concepts>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template<random_access_iterator T1, random_access_iterator T2>
    requires (unsigned_integral<typename iterator_traits<T1>::value_type>
              && !is_same_v<typename iterator_traits<T1>::value_type, bool>)
struct permutated_iterator
{
private:

    T1 p{}; ///< Permutation vector iterator.
    T2 v{}; ///< Permutated vector iterator.

public:

    /// Default constructor is needed from std::forward_iterator concept.
    constexpr permutated_iterator() = default;

    /** Constructor for dense permutated vector iterator.
    \param p Permutation vector iterator, pointing in current position of this iterator.
    \param v The permutated vector iterator, pointing in start of vector. */
    constexpr permutated_iterator(T1 p, T2 v) noexcept : p{p}, v{v} {}

    constexpr bool operator==(const permutated_iterator &it) const noexcept { return p == it.p; }
    constexpr auto operator<=>(const permutated_iterator &it) const noexcept { return p <=> it.p; }
};

int main()
{
    using piter = std::span<const unsigned char, 2>::iterator;
    using viter = std::span<int, 2>::iterator ;
    using cpiter = std::basic_const_iterator<piter> ;
    using iter1 = permutated_iterator<piter, viter> ;
    using iter2 = permutated_iterator<cpiter, viter>;
    static_assert(std::totally_ordered<viter>);
    static_assert(std::totally_ordered<piter>);
    static_assert(std::totally_ordered<cpiter>);
    static_assert(std::totally_ordered<iter1>);
    static_assert(std::totally_ordered<iter2>);   // PROBLEM!!!!

    // this is ok: iter2() == iter2()
    // this is not ok: iter2() > iter2()
}    


Thanks for chop down the code, but I don't think that permutated_iterator is an std::random_access_iterator anymore.

It's not, but you don't need it to be to expose the problem. Here's even more stripped: https://godbolt.org/z/MhM6Yqfo4

I'm pretty sure this is a gcc bug but am struggling to reduce it. With creduce's help I came up with this, but that version actually compiles on gcc trunk whereas yours doesn't.

Reduced it to this
